# Maximum current available from a source

Tags: voltage, current-measurement

How can we find the maximum current a source can provide,say if my device need 1amp and the source can provide 2 amps in the rated voltage will my device only draw 1 amphere or will it draw 2 amp in this case is there any chance my device may burn out of over current.

Answer (score 0):

your device will only consume 1 A and will be safe

Comment: Depends on the device. Mohammed, what's the nature of the device?

Comment: I'd say it depends also on the nature of the source. If it's a voltage source it will try to force the voltage across the device, letting it draw current accordingly; if it's a current source, it will try to force its nominal current - the voltage will be a 'side effect' of that.

Comment: Iam trying to use atx power suply to power my mobile phone using  dc to dc CC CV buck converter

Answer (score 0):

Your device /load will only draw what it needs for its normal operations. But in general if the source is able to supply much larger current than what actually the load needs, it will be a good practice to install a current limiting device (a fuse or thermal breakers) in the current path.

This is necessary because in the case of failure the internal parts of your load probably will fail catastrophically if incoming current is unlimited.

An example of this is charging a mobile phone from a standard USB charger and charge the same phone from +5V sourced from 20 Ampere Atx power supply.

In case of charge controller failure, can you imagine what 20 Amps will do to the type C USB port, the tiny wires it is attached to, the internal components of your phone?